# HTML - alternate element for explicit links?

Tags: html

`<a>` without `href`? If I want a link's text to equal its target, is there no way to declare it without duplicating the target URL in the source?

in other words: does a shorter version of this exist?

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page.html">http://www.domain.com/page.html</a>
```

this does not work:

```
<a>http://www.domain.com/page.html</a>
```

is there no element for this purpose?

Comment: You could have `<a href="page.html">link</a>` and then use JavaScript to replace the text content with the href value.

Comment: Thanks everyone for great responses. I am, as always, in awe of the quality of this site, keep it up guys and gals.

Comment: I accepted JCOC611's answer because i would never do something like this with javascript and his answer was the most agreeable and informative. There should be a way for questioners to accept multiple questions. The answer is clearly NO to all my original questions.

Comment: If multiple answers have the same value, you choose the one that was posted first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with plain HTML. It is possible with JavaScript, although I don't recommend it since crawlers wouldn't be able to follow the link and that would be just lazy.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, a click-able anchor always needs a hyperlink reference.

As an aside, you could use javascript and short-hand it, but you're adding a dependency to the visitor now.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
  if (links[l].innerHTML.indexOf('http') == 0 && !links[l].href)
    links[l].href = links[l].innerHTML;
}
```

*Very Primitive, but [works](http://www.jsfiddle.net/qxFef/).*

Comment: this goes for a lot of people on this site too... how is it even possible for you to reply with this much relevant content in 3 minutes? And you put some content into the jsfiddle example too.

Comment: Heh, some people live to code. ;-) As you get to use the site and build your reputation up, you'll realize it's not all smoke and mirrors. I can post an answer with a single letter, then go back and edit it with more in-depth information. Around 2k rep you'll see what I mean. ;-)

Comment: ohhh thats cheating though. I do tend to continue to edit my post well after it first goes up, i hadn't thought of that :)

Answer (score 2):

No. It definitely needs a `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> is there no tag for this purpose?

no

Answer (score -3):

You can always define it as below and then use some Javascript to do the rest.

```
<a href="#">http://www.domain.com/page.html</a>
```

An anchor tag needs a href, it's just how it is. If you don't want to use a href, do:

```
<span class="mockAnchor">http://www.domain.com/page.html</span>
```

And have your own CSS for that to make it look like an anchor (and add a click event etc.)

Comment: No, that will link to the empty anchor in the current document, and will completely ignore the text inside the link

Comment: This will keep the user on the current page, the link's target points to the current page.